# What is marking_store "service" option in Symfony Workflow

Tags: symfony, workflow, symfony5

In Symfony's workflow configuration reference, under the **marking_store** configuration (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#marking-store) there is an option called "service":

> marking_store
>
> **type**: array
>
> Each marking store can define any of these options:
>
> - arguments (type: array)
> - service (type: string)
> - type (type: string allow value: "method")

What this "service" option does and how it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to register the workflow as a service, for injection i guess.
See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22031

Comment: Hi Florent, thanks for the answer. Do you mean that someone can use it to inject a custom implementation of MarkingStoreInterface?